# APC list of keys

Tags: list, key, apc

I have a 35MB file with ~ 1 million lines. I loaded every line to APC as a key (10-12 character) and an integer as value. If i fetch about the 80% of the entries dont exist, only the lines from end of the file are there. Is it possible that APC's memory got full and the first entries got overwritten by the new ones?

apc.shm_size: 512M

512 Mb should enough to store data from a 35MB file, shouldnt?

Is there any visualization tool (WAMP) to see the list of entries and memory usage of APC?

***EDIT***

I made some modification on code to see when will be the first entry overwritten. It was about the 220.000th row. Additionally i increased the apc.shm_size to 1024M. And the number of the rows increased by 2 times. Why do I need more then 2GB to store 35MB data in the memory?

If i crease the apc.shm_size over from 1024M to 1025, Apache wont start.